# Why does formatting a JList cell using HTML lead to the text being centered in the cell?

Tags: java, html

I have a JList in which I am formatting the text before it is added to the JList cell using HTML. I'm doing this because I'm lazy and don't want to get complex with a cellRenderer. I only need 2 separate lines in each JList cell so HTML just seemed quicker and easier for such a simple requirement, however when I run this it correctly formats it, however, the text does not start on the edge of the button. I'm assuming this is because the HTML takes up space in whitespaces in which case I assume I can't fix that?

```
 public static void receiveDataEmailList(String data) {
    Scanner scLine = new Scanner(data).useDelimiter("&");
    int num = scLine.nextInt();
    String[] emails = new String[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        emails[i] = "" + "<html><ul style=\"list-style-type:none;\"><li style=\"font-size:10px\">" + scLine.next() + "</li><li style=\"font-size:8px\">" + "Subject: " + "Hello" + "</li></ul></html>";
    }
    EmailList.setListOfEmails(emails);
}
```

Comment: A JList uses a JLabel as the renderer. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. So you can simply create a frame with a JLabel that contains your HTML. See if you have the same problem. I would guess this is just how a HTML list is formatted. Instead of using a unordered list maybe just use a `<br>` tag to force a new line. Maybe an HTML expert will have a better suggestion.

Comment: I would definitely use `<br>` instead of a list for multiple lines.  Changing the list-style-type doesn’t remove the indentation of list items.